# User Function to slice query output

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm performing a query on my Neo4j database and getting back the expected results, although it's in a different format. What I want my output to look like is this...

```
{"nodes":[
  {"id":"James Gunn"},
  {"id":"Zoe Saldana"},
  {"id":"Bradley Cooper"},
  {"id":"Vin Diesel"},
  {"id":"Chris Pratt"},
  {"id": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
    "year":2014.0,
    "director":"James Gunn",
    "rating":8.1,
    "runtime":121.0,
    "description":"<Enter long desc here>",
    "label":"Movie",
    "actors":["Chris Pratt","Vin Diesel","Bradley Cooper","Zoe Saldana"],
    "revenue":333.13,
    "genres":["Action","Adventure","Sci-Fi"],
    "name":"Guardians of the Galaxy",
    "rank":1.0,
    "votes":757074.0,
    "metascore":76.0}], 
"links":[
    {"source":"Zoe Saldana","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"},
    {"source":"Bradley Cooper","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"},
    {"source":"Vin Diesel","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"},
    {"source":"Chris Pratt","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"}]}
```

Instead, I'm getting the same, just with an extra "{"nodes" : " at the beginning I'd like to omit.
Here's what I mean

```
{"nodes":  (<----- REMOVE/OMIT THIS LINE)  
  {"nodes":[
  {"id":"James Gunn"},
  {"id":"Zoe Saldana"},
  {"id":"Bradley Cooper"},
  {"id":"Vin Diesel"},
  {"id":"Chris Pratt"},
  {"id": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
    "year":2014.0,
    "director":"James Gunn",
    "rating":8.1,
    "runtime":121.0,
    "description":"<Long desc>",
    "label":"Movie",
    "actors":["Chris Pratt","Vin Diesel","Bradley Cooper","Zoe Saldana"],
    "revenue":333.13,
    "genres":["Action","Adventure","Sci-Fi"],
    "name":"Guardians of the Galaxy",
    "rank":1.0,
    "votes":757074.0,
    "metascore":76.0}],

  "links":[
    {"source":"Zoe Saldana","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"},
    {"source":"Bradley Cooper","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"},
    {"source":"Vin Diesel","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"},
    {"source":"Chris Pratt","target":"Guardians of the Galaxy"}
   ]
   }
}   <-----(ALSO THIS LINE THAT CLOSES IT)
```

Here is my current query

```
`CALL apoc.export.json.query("MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE m.name = 'Guardians of the Galaxy'
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(m, {maxLevel:1}) YIELD nodes, relationships
WITH [node in nodes | node {.*, id:node.name, label:labels(node)[0]}] as nodes, 
     [rel in relationships | rel {.*, source:startNode(rel).name, target:endNode(rel).name}] as rels
WITH {nodes:nodes, links:rels} as nodes
RETURN nodes"
        , "file://./limit.json", {})`
```

What my question is is how do I write a user function that would allow me to slice the string to be formatted how I'd like?
I'm assuming it'd be something like `RETURN Slicing(nodes)` but from what I've read user functions are only allowed in Java and I'm using JavaScript in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of composing a new json doc, maybe you can try returning the nodes and links directly as in,

Instead of,

```
...
WITH {nodes:nodes, links:rels} as nodes
RETURN nodes   
...
```

try

```
...
RETURN nodes, rels as links 
...
```